# Entity framework - inserting into column creates duplicate

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using EF 6.1.3. Basically I have two classes:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Card
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public User CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Naturally, checking the table definitions, a foreign key relationship is created between `CreatedBy` of `Card` and `Id` of `User`. `Card` now has a `CreatedBy_Id` column for this.

I seeded a default `User` (Id = 1), which is stored somewhere in a variable which we'll call `CurrentUser`. Now, when I want to enter a card:

```
context.Cards.Add(new Card
{
    Name = "Card of Water",
    CreatedBy = CurrentUser
});
context.SaveChanges();
```

The result I get is the new `Card` is created, but the `CreatedBy` didn't store `CurrentUser` reference. Rather, a new `User` was created (Id = 2), and that is what got stored in the new `Card`'s `CreatedBy`.

How can I correct this? Thanks.

**EDIT:**

`CurrentUser` is set a value at the start of the program, in the `Load` event of the starting form. It is declared as a global variable:

```
CurrentUser = context.Users.First(); //In load event
```

The adding is just for testing really, in a Button. The code above is all there is to it.

Comment: From where `CurrentUser` variable comes? Post full code here and I will help you out.

Comment: that doesn't create relationship in db

Comment: I may be wrong here, but since `User` has an id which is of type int, shouldn't your `Card` class have a variable called `public int CreatedById { get; set; }` or something, which stores the actual integer ID of the User who created it?

Comment: @JenishRabadiya In response to your question, `CurrentUser` is set at program startup, something along `CurrentUser = context.Users.First()`. There is no additional code before the `context.Cards.Add()`.

Comment: @AwonDanag Post full code in the Question and update it

Comment: @KeyurPATEL EF automatically created a column `CreatedById`, like I mentioned.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya There, updated it. Thanks.

Comment: @AwonDanag debug it and check whether the value for CurrentUser is correct before save changes is invoked and if not then reinitialize it before you add instance of `Card` to `context.Cards`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Card
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CreatedBy")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public User CreatedBy { get; set; }
}

context.Cards.Add(new Card
{
    Name = "Card of Water",
    UserId = CurrentUser.Id,
    CreatedBy = CurrentUser
});
context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue you need to establish **Foreign Key** relationship between these two tables and as following:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }         // primary key
}

public class Card
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CreatedBy")]
    public int UserId { get; set; } // Foreign Key

    public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }
    //use virtual keyword to allow lazy loading while execution
}

context.Cards.Add(new Card
{
    Name = "Card of Water",
    UserId = CurrentUser.Id
    //No need to insert CreatedBy user object here as we are passing UserId
});
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: How can I get the `ForeignKey` attribute?

Comment: @JenishRabadiya Not required? How so? Can you please explain?

Comment: @AwonDanag Entityframework does take care of it when you assign related entity like `CreatedBy = CurrentUser` but CurrentUser should be referentially equal to the instance you created. That is the reason I asked you in comment to the question. How does you initialize `CurrentUser` and post the full code before `context.Cards.Add(new Card.....`